# UITableView programmatically select option

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a view that has several options, and inside it is a table view that gets data from a server.

Is there a way to have the table view automatically select the first option on load, i.e. in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [UITableView's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

If you want the delegate callback, you'll have to call it manually:

```
if ([self.tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)])
    [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

You'd probably want to cache that index path in a local variable, then.

Answer (score 1):

To select a row, you can use the instance method `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` of `UITableView` to select a row.

But why do you want to do it in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: It makes sense to do it in viewDidLoad (viewDidAppear: also works) so the user sees the first row selected when the view is loaded.

Comment: I think `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` is a better option. The reason I asked is because I do not think that UITableView loads its data from the data source in the `viewDidLoad` method (unless maybe you explicitly call `reloadData` inside your implementation of `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: I want to do it within an in statement, i.e. if only one result gets published to the tableView, then it gets selected. If there are more, you have to manually select one.

Comment: There are two ways:

1. Since you control the table view's data source, you can check the number of rows published directly in your data source, OR

2. You can use UITableView's `-numberOfSections` and `-numberOfRowsInSection:` method to find out the number of sections and rows currently displayed by the table view.